# Looking for GIS data for Curitiba, Brazil?

Tags: data, transportation, footprint, brazil

I am wondering if anyone knows where to find building footprints, road network, transit, or environment feature data for Curitiba, Brazil.

Comment: http://curitibaemdados.ippuc.org.br/ hope your Portuguese is up to scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Brazilian Institute of Geography and Statistics (IBGE)](http://www.ibge.gov.br/english/geociencias/default_prod.shtm#REC_NAT) web page.  Also take a look at the statewide data for the state of Parana at [GeoComm](http://data.geocomm.com/catalog/BR/136474/datalist.html) (aka GIS Data Depot).  USGS [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) has great global remote sensing products.  The screenshot shows a downloadable Global Land Survey dataset over Curitiba.

[image]